# How to generate UML Diagrams from VS2012 Professional Edition?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

For the user of professional edition in VS2012, is there a method to generate the UML (CLASS, SEQUENCE) Diagrams from VS2012?

I have already done implenting my solution project in VS2012. Now i want to generate the class diagram for it.Therefore, if anyone knows about it?

If please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Upgrade to Visual Studio Ultimate :(

Answer (score 4):

As has already been noted, the Professional edition of Visual Studio doesn't allow you to generate sequence diagrams.

An alternative would be to use a proper UML tool, such as [Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html). This offers far more modelling capabilities than Visual Studio, and has support for C++, C#, Java and a host of other languages. And yes, it can generate class and sequence diagrams from source and binary code (binary requires the second-cheapest license).

Answer (score 2):

Generating a Sequence Diagram is an [Ultimate Feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee317485.aspx).

> In Visual Studio Ultimate, generate a sequence diagram to help you
>   visualize and understand how the code implements a particular method.
>   A sequence diagram describes an interaction between objects as a
>   series of lifelines and messages. Lifelines represent instances of
>   objects, and messages represent method calls between those objects.
>   You can generate sequence diagrams from Visual C# .NET or Visual Basic
>   .NET code.

Class diagrams are a standard feature of [Visual Studio Professional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x35cds6.aspx).

Comment: What about VS 2012 Premium?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% about professional, but in Ultimate it is under `Architecture -> New Diagram`

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your function and choose option "Generate Sequence Diagram" VS 2012